# Select element by id containing a special character

Tags: jquery

I have an id in input box containing a division sign. How can I select this this element?

```
<input type="text" title="City" name="billing[city]" value="" class="input-text  required-entry" id="billing:city">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the element as:

```
var elem =   $("input[id='billing:city']");
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery 3.0 has been introduced [jQuery.escapeSelector()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/):

> Escapes any character that has a special meaning in a CSS selector.

```js
var eleSelector = '#' + $.escapeSelector( "billing:city");

// with an older jQuery version
//var eleSelector = '#billing\\:city";

console.log('eleSelector: ' + eleSelector);

console.log($(eleSelector).get(0).outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" title="City" name="billing[city]" value="" class="input-text  required-entry" id="billing:city">
```

Comment: jquery-1.10.2.min.js, jQuery.escapeSelector is not a function

Comment: @deepak with an older jQuery version you can write: ***var eleSelector = '#billing\\:city";***